# PHP htmlentities and htmlspecialchars are breaking my strings

Tags: php, html

I have a description field in my application, and if I include a quote like this: ’ it breaks everything. I was using htmlentities() on the entire description field, and so I tried htmlspecialchars() but it breaks as well.

In the screenshot below, I sent the string "I’d like this to work" and got the follow mess

[image: This is what my string looks like after being run through htmlentities]
[This is what my string looks like after being run through htmlentities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fTSi.jpg)

I've had this issue in the past, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Set your document's encoding to `UTF-8` and see if that fixes it. Also, if you're geting the &acirc; it may mean that you're double-encoding, so the & is actually an &amp;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing my code from

```
$text = htmlentities( $text, ENT_QUOTES );
```

to:

```
$text = htmlentities( $text, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8' );
```

Which is weird, because PHP lists the default setting as utf-8.

Comment: From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php): *"If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards."* So utf-8 being default is fairly new. I always use a wrapper function so you can change stuff like this easily, something like `escape_html()`

Answer (score 1):

If I just have to replace certain characters I'll sometimes just create a simple find and replace script.

```
<?php
  $bad = array('’', '&'); // add whatever you don't want here
  $good = array('&rsquo;', '&amp;'); // replace it here
  $description_field = str_replace($bad, $good, $description_field);
?>
```

Comment: But I don't want to have to replace them, I just want my script not to break.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `htmlentities` and `htmlspecialchars` are not UTF-8-safe functions. They see the first byte of a Unicode character as an HTML entity to encode, then when it comes time for the browser to read the supposedly UTF-8 content, it sees an HTML entity followed by two invalid bytes left over.

You might need to look into functions like [`mb_ereg_replace`](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) and manually replace unsafe characters:

```
$output = mb_ereg_replace("/</","&lt;",$input);
```

That's all you *really* need to make a string HTML-safe. I can't seem to find a multibyte-safe `str_replace`, but this works just as well, and it will ensure you never have problems with UTF-8 characters.